# sass compass magic sprites active state

Tags: sass, compass-sass

I'm using compass to generate my icons and their hover states. The active state is the same as the hover state, and **I'd like to keep my sprite map from being bloated** with duplicate icons. Is there any way to make it add an active class to the same coordinates as the hover state?

```
    @import 'sprites/*.png';
    @include all-sprites-sprites;
```

generates:

```
    .sprites-left {
      background-position: 0 -16px;
    }
    .sprites-left:hover, .sprites-left.left_hover, .sprites-left.left-hover {
      background-position: -18px -16px;
    }
```

I'd like to add

```
    .sprites-left.active  {
      background-position: -18px -16px;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is as close to a solution as I could come up with.

```
@import 'sprites/*.png'; // sprites to include
@include all-sprites-sprites; // creates all sprites

// Manually extend each to add active states.
.sprites-engaged.active{ @extend .sprites-engaged:hover; }
.sprites-married.active{ @extend .sprites-married:hover; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you [read the docs](http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/spriting/)? The Selector Control section covers this:

```
@import 'sprites/*.png';

.sprites-left {
  &:hover, &.active { @include sprites-sprite(name_for_hover) }
  ... etc
}
```

Comment: Re-read your comment. I think you're missing that I'm using it to generate all the sprites names based on the file name. .sprites-left was an example of what was generated. It would defeat the purpose to have to write in every single sprite name.